# git-rebase cause directory link number decrease to 0

Tags: git, ubuntu

## I have Tree questions:

1. Why git-rebase throw `fast-forward` failed (the commits are in all local)
2. How to create a directory with link number 0
3. How to delete the directory(link number 0) without removing the parent dir

## What I do before:

1. throw an error When I use the webstorm to reword ci

```sh
$ git -c core.quotepath=false -c log.showSignature=false -c core.commentChar= rebase --interactive --preserve-merges --no-autosquash 855fc6a36795bfce94b9295123d4d3d24c8d1f5b
Cannot fast-forward to 3203c385af50df0e2564530465be6553d13c4916
```

2. then the progress of rebase is aborted, but one of my directory`s link number goes to 0

```sh
$ ls -l | grep cu
drwxrwxrwx 0 paul paul   4096 Aug 23 02:36 custom-module
```

## Env

```sh
$ uname -a 
Linux DESKTOP-VAMO8F7 4.4.0-17763-Microsoft #379-Microsoft Wed Mar 06 19:16:00 PST 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Something is seriously wrong with your system. *Git* cannot set the link count of a directory to zero, and zero is not a valid link count for a directory (the minimum is 2 for most directories and 1 for some oddball cases). See https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/427551/162084

Comment: @torek: Link count != 0 is true for standard, local Unix filesystems. But the uname show `Microsoft` in its output - so it might be an artefact of some Linux-Windows emulation. Or it might be related to a remote filesystem which is mounted into Linux.

Comment: @torek Thanks, By the way, Do you have any idea to delete this invalid directory without deleting it\`s parent directory.

Comment: Paul Han: no, no idea now to deal with it. @A.H. Yes, it might be, but it's definitely weird. It messes with optimizations in `find` and it violates all the rules. If Microsoft did this, they're doing the embrace-and-extend-to-the-point-of-breakage thing again.